# Why should be int[i]=int[i]+d in the question of combining key-value pairs（combine chart records）？

Tags: java, stack

The question is:

The data table includes indices and values(in int type), please combine the records with same indices, like add together values that both have same indices, output key with ascending order

Input:
the number of key-value pairs
then pairs of index and value with space in the middle

Output:
combined key-value pairs(multiple lines)

Example:
Input

```
4
0 1
0 2 
1 2 
3 4
```

Output:

```
0 3
1 2
3 4
```

Runnable code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line;
        Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        line=br.readLine();
        int[] ints = new int[Integer.valueOf(line)];
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            int a = line.indexOf(" ");//a=1
            int b = line.indexOf(" ",a);//b=3
            Integer c = Integer.valueOf(line.substring(0,a));
            Integer d = Integer.valueOf(line.substring(a+1));
            ints[c] = ints[c]+d;
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<ints.length;i++){
            if(ints[i]!=0){
                sb.append(i).append(" ").append(ints[i]).append("\n");
            }
        }
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
```

I dont quite understand why `int[i]=int[i]+d`, i thought it should be `int[i] = c + d`

I would be really grateful if anyone could help me with it.

Comment: `c` is the index (or key) and `d` is the value. You want to add all the values. `int[i]` is the sum of previous values at the given index (or `0` if it is the first occurrence of that index).

Comment: Understood！！Thank you!!